# split string and concatenating to remove a portion of string

Tags: r, concatenation, strsplit

I am trying to remove a portion of a string. The best I can come up with is to strsplit and then concatenate (maybe there is an easier way.

```
list<-as.character(c("joe_joe_ID1000", "bob_bob_ID20000"))
list<-strsplit(list, "_")
```

I would like my output to be "joe joe" and "bob bob" but I am unclear on how to concatenate the resulting strsplit list. And perhaps there is an even easier way
Thanks.

Comment: Try `paste(list[[1]][1],list[[1]][2])` and `paste(list[[2]][1],list[[2]][2])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sapply() and paste() you can do this:

```
sapply(list, function(x) paste(x[1:2], collapse = " "))
[1] "joe joe" "bob bob"
```

Or something more akin to akrun's solution but slightly different:

```
c("joe_joe_ID1000", "bob_bob_ID20000") %>% 
  sub("[^_]*$", " ", .) %>%
  gsub("_", " ", ., fixed = TRUE) %>%
  trimws()
[1] "joe joe" "bob bob"
```

Original data:

```
list<-as.character(c("joe_joe_ID1000", "bob_bob_ID20000"))
list<-strsplit(list, "_")
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `sub`, capture words as a group and then use backreferences (`\\1 \\2`) of the captured group to format in the specified way

```
sub("^(\\w+)_(\\w+)_.*", "\\1 \\2", list)
#[1] "joe joe" "bob bob"
```

NOTE: `list` is a type.  It is better to name objects differently

#### data

```
list <- c("joe_joe_ID1000", "bob_bob_ID20000")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `stringr`'s `str_split` then paste together using apply.

```
apply(stringr::str_split(list, "_", simplify = T)[,1:2], 1, paste, collapse=" ")
[1] "joe joe" "bob bob"
```

Or use a `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
as.tibble(list) %>% 
  separate(value,letters[1:2], sep="_", remove = F, extra = "drop") %>% 
  unite(result, a,b, sep=" ")
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  value           result 
  <chr>           <chr>  
1 joe_joe_ID1000  joe joe
2 bob_bob_ID20000 bob bob

.Last.value %>% pull(result)
[1] "joe joe" "bob bob"
```